# dynamic query for multiple items from a single record from one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (arealist) which has an ID field and multiple fields for tracking membership by year (M2012, M2013, etc) where each year's value is Yes or No.  I can build a query to extract the fields I want (`SELECT M2011, M2012, M2013, M2014 FROM arealist WHERE ID = 675;`) but the fields will be growing in the future years adding M2015, M2016, M2017, etc.

HOW can I build a dynamic query that extracts the current Year info plus 4 years back. 
Example: EndYear = 2014 - need 4 years back so answer will be M2011, M2012, M2013, M2014).

`SELECT ??? FROM arealist WHERE ??? RANGE (BegYear to EndYear) AND ID = 675;`

Comment: can you change the schema now before it's too late?  you should be adding rows not columns for this kind of data.

Comment: I like this idea, but each row is a member (person) and these fields track the year's in which they were a member (ie, member 675 was a member of the club in 2011, 2012, 2013 etc). That mean that these values would have to become its own table something like (ID, Year, Yes/No). seems like it would complicate things.  I will surely consider this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the year a proper field, changing 1 row with columns  M2011, M2012, M2013, M2014,ID to 4 rows with columns M, YEAR, ID (YEAR takes integer values from 2011 to 2014).

Next year, you add one row for each ID with YEAR=2015, and so on, without changing the table definition or your code:

```
SELECT M from AREALIST where ID= ? AND YEAR >= ? AND YEAR <= ?
```

Comment: As noted above I can agree in principle with your suggestion - However, in this case the current record hold a large number of fields and so making this into a copy for each member of the club so adding records would violate the normalization rules.  Make these into their own table is an alternative to your suggestion and likely what I will need to do.  Thanks for the idea - you got me off in a useable direction.

Comment: Sure, if the key for current or descriptive data is ID only and the key for yearly data is ID + year the two column groups should be split into two tables.